# Why is the time zone not set correctly from characters

Tags: r, timezone

I wonder, why R does not get the correct time zone. Do I miss something?

```
my_str <- c("2016-01-01 00:04:52 CET", "2016-01-01 00:09:52 CET", 
            "2016-01-01 00:18:04 CET", "2016-01-01 00:18:49 CET")
my_t <- as.POSIXct(my_str)
attributes(my_t)
# $class
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
# 
# $tzone
# [1] ""

my_t <- lubridate::ymd_hms(my_str)
attributes(my_t)
# $tzone
# [1] "UTC"
# 
# $class
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

This "solves" the problem but I wonder why I have to take care about the obvious:

```
my_t <- as.POSIXct(my_str, tz="CET")
attributes(my_t)
# $class
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
# 
# $tzone
# [1] "CET"
```

Comment: Study `help("strptime")`. The time zone cannot be parsed from the string (presumably because most operating systems don't offer that).

Comment: @Roland Ok, there are quite some pitfalls and the docs state: "... the standards say that an empty string should be output if the offset is unknown, but some systems use the offsets for the time zone in use for the current year."

Comment: Again, R uses OS facilities for this. If you have complaints direct them to your OS vendor or use an alternative as shown below (package anytime uses a C library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The awesome `anytime` package solves the issue:

```
my_str <- c("2016-01-01 00:04:52 CET", "2016-01-01 00:09:52 CET", 
            "2016-01-01 00:18:04 CET", "2016-01-01 00:18:49 CET")
library(anytime)

my_t <- anytime(my_str)

attributes(my_t)
#> $class
#> [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
#> 
#> $tzone
#> [1] "Europe/Berlin"
```